# How to test that all objects used in a function are inited first?

Tags: object, reflection

I have a function and a few pre defined objects, which I use inside the function.
In the function, I first run another function on each of those objects, to init them.
The code looks like this: (case 1)

```
class A {
fun foo1(){
init(objectA)
init(objectB)
println(objectA)
println(objectB)
}
}
```

I want to write a test which tests that all params used in this function `foo1` were first init by fun `init`.
This case is forbidden: (case 2)

```
class A {
fun foo1(){
init(objectA)
println(objectA)
println(objectB)
}
}
```

1. How do I iterate over all objects used in function `foo1`?
2. How do I test that an `init` function was invoked on an object?

I have tried searching google with no results so far.
I assume I should use reflection in some way, but not sure how.

Expected: test pass on case 1, test fail on case 2.

Comment: Tag the question with the language you are actually using. This is not Java code.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use reflection for this. It's nearly always a sign of a design flaw.

Better would be to restructure your code for testability. In particular, inject dependencies.

```
ClassA {
    private final List<ClassB> objectList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final Consumer<ClassB> initialiser;

    public ClassA(Consumer<ClassB> initialiser) {
        this.initialiser = initialiser;
    }

    public void addObject(ClassB objB) {
        this.objectList(objB);
    }

    public void foo1() {
        objectList.forEach(initialiser::accept);
        ...
    }
}
```

then, using JUnit and Mockito (for example):

```
@Test
void testAllObjectsInitialised() {
    Consumer<ClassB> mockInitialiser = mock(Consumer.class);
    ClassB objB1 = mock(ClassB.class);
    ClassB objB2 = mock(ClassB.class);
    ClassA testA = new ClassA(mockInitialiser);
    testA.addObject(objB1);
    testA.addObject(objB2);
    testA.foo1();
    verify(mockInitialiser).accept(objB1);
    verify(mockInitialiser).accept(objB2));
 }
```